# How recognize any up to 2 worlds after different prefixes in sentence

Tags: regex, regex-group

I know this is not new question but i need to make some preprocess and make  a pattern with REGEX that replaces/finds first/last names after some prefixes like `Dear John doe,` , `Dear Mr's John D!` , `Hi John` , `Hi Mr John` , `Hello John` , etc ....

Suppose I have between 1 or 2 words (first name/ first+last) in each sentence and it could contain comma in the end of the name but not must.

example:

```
Hi Mr John, we are planning to go out
```

or

```
Hi Mr John we are planning to go out
```

should be modified respectively:

```
Hi Mr @name, we are planning to go out
```

or

```
Hi Mr @name we are planning to go out
```

I've tried so far but it not correct solution , it could done better.

```
((?i)Mr's|(?i)Mr|(?i)Hi|(?i)Dear)(/(\w+\s){1,}\w+[.?!]/)
```

regards

Comment: Try `(?i)\b(Mr(?:'s)?|Dear|Hi(?!,?\s*Mrs?\b))\s+\w+(?:\s+\w+)?` and replace with `$1 @name`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZOrjJ8/2).

Comment: Maybe [`((?:(?:(?i)Hi|Dear|Hello)\s+)?(?:(?i)M[rs]?s|[MD]r)\.?\s+)([A-Z]\w+(?:\s[A-Z]\w+)*)(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/RncJG1/1/) where the three capture groups are the part before the name, the name, and the part after the name.

Comment: NB: I never saw "Mr's" as a title. Shouldn't that be Mrs or Mss? See [Salutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salutation)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that matches 'we' https://regex101.com/r/ZOrjJ8/3

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/ZOrjJ8/4.  I removed the `i` modifier

Comment: @trincot thanks good solution , can you look on this example like -  Dear John Smith, we are planning to go out not working  , and when the name with dash like John-Smith

Comment: If your engine is similar to PCRE, you may only apply case insensitivity to a group, see [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/ZOrjJ8/5).

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew , Thanks Good solution too , what about "Dear Mr John Smith, we are planning to go out" ...?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/ZOrjJ8/6

Comment: thanks it helped , last case when i have <firstname-lastname> like :Dear Mr John-Smith, we are planning to go out

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew ,   sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may use

```
\b((?:\s*(?i:Mr(?:'s)?|Dear|Hi(?!,?\s*Mrs?\b)))+)\s+[A-Z]\w*(?:[\s-]+[A-Z]\w*)?
```

With the following replacement:

```
$1 @name
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZOrjJ8/8)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `((?:\s*(?i:Mr(?:'s)?|Dear|Hi(?!,?\s*Mrs?\b)))+)` - Group 1 (referred to as `$1` or `\1` from the replacement pattern) that matches 1 or more repetitions of the following pattern sequence:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?i:Mr(?:'s)?|Dear|Hi(?!,?\s*Mrs?\b))` - a case insensitive modifier group matching:

    - `Mr(?:'s)?|` - `Mr` and then an optional `'s` substring, or
    - `Dear|` - a `Dear` substring or
    - `Hi(?!,?\s*Mrs?\b)` - `Hi` that is not followed with an optional comma, 0+ whitespaces, `Mr` or `Mrs` as whole words
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars (letters, digits, `_`, to only match ASCII letters use `[A-Za-z]*` instead)
- `(?:[\s-]+[A-Z]\w*)?` - an optional group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `[\s-]+` - 1 or more whitespaces or `-`
  - `[A-Z]\w*` - an uppercase ASCII letter and then 0+ word chars.